# Can someone will please explain the output of this program?

Tags: c, pointers

In the below example pointer `p` is a pointer to a variable `a`.

I have incremented the value of `p` by 1, which increases the value by 4 because it is int.
But when I try to print the value of `*p`, some different value is displayed.

I have also attached the output with the program.

Can somebody explain why that value of `*p` is displayed?

```
//  POINTERS    

#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

int a = 3;

int *p = &a;

printf("Value of p %d   \n",p);
printf("Value of *p %d  \n",*p);

p = p+1;

printf("After changing : value of p %d  \n",p);
printf("After changing :  value of *p %d \n",*p);

return 0;

}
```

**Output:**

Link
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTYlq.jpg

Comment: What value did you expect? What is the purpose of that last `printf`? There are no comments in the code.

Comment: You've incremented the value of p by 1 indeed. That changes the address that pointer is pointing to. In this case, this address contains garbage value - so the behavior is undefined when you try to dereference it.

Comment: If you want to get `4` as an output, you'll have to change `p = p+1;` to `*p = *p+1;`

Comment: This program has undefined behaviour and is allowed to produce any output whatsoever, or none at all. [Here is one possible output](https://godbolt.org/z/oezj3cdE3).

Comment: Your output is plain text. Please just copy&paste it as formatted text into your question (you can use the edit-button below your question) instead of showing pictures.

Comment: @justASimpleLonelyProgrammer No was just asking why that value of p is getting printed .

Comment: @davidSchwartz was not expecting any value just wanted to know why that value of p was getting printed

Comment: @Leveling_up Then I hope Chase's comment answered your question.

Comment: @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer yea!

Answer (score 3):

> Can somebody explain why that value of *p is displayed?

No, no one can explain why the last print of `*p` gives the value you see.

And tomorrow it may print another value... or not print at all... or your program may crash... or something different may happen...

It's called **undefined behavior**.

You are trying to read a memory location (i.e. the original `p` + 1) as if there is an `int` located at that location. But there isn't... the C standard doesn't define what has to happen when you do that. So anything may happen.

Further notice that you actually have **undefined behavior** already here:

```
printf("Value of p %d   \n",p);
                   ^^
                   Wrong for pointers and therefore undefined behavior
```

To print a pointer you must use `%p` and cast the pointer to a void pointer. Like:

```
printf("Value of p %p   \n", (void*)p);
                   ^^        ^^^^^^^
             Specifier       cast to void-pointer
           for void-pointer
```

So a legal version of your program:

```
int a = 3;

int *p = &a;

printf("Value of p %p   \n", (void*)p);
printf("Value of *p %d  \n",*p);

p = p+1;

printf("After changing : value of p %p  \n", (void*)p);
// printf("After changing :  value of *p %d \n",*p); <-- Illegal so commented out
```

Comment: Ok so behaviour is undefined!! Understood  thanks 

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing memory you do not (necessarily) have access to.

Imagine `a` (4-bytes long) is here

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | |a|a|a|a| | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 ^ ^ ^         ^ ^ ^ ^ ^   <== memory you do not have access to
       \------ |           <== p points here
               \------     <== p+1 points here and the pointer is valid
```

Accessing memory you do not have access to is **Undefined Behaviour**.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is **undefined** as we cannot say that the value is present in the new address location.